# GitHub Issue related to placeholder in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working in AngularJs and have applied a placeholder in all my input form elements. Due to this the $dirty is implicitly true when the page loads and due to this the error message is displaying without any user modification in IE10(also known as GitHub issue).The code works fine in firefox and chrome. Is there any solution to this GitHub issue?

Here is code:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required autofocus autocomplete="on" autofill>
```

Please fill out this field

--edit--
format code block

Comment: Did you try using novalidate to the form? and use $dirty?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you saw is caused by a combination of the IE10 and the `required` directive.

To workaround it you could write a custom directive to do the validation instead of the angular's `required` directive like this:

```
.directive('myRequired', function () {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;

      var validator = function(value) {
        var isEmpty = ctrl.$isEmpty(value);
        ctrl.$setValidity('required', !isEmpty);
        return isEmpty ? '' : value;
      };

      ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
    }
  };
});
```

and then replace `required` with `my-required` in html:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" my-required autofocus autocomplete="on" autofill />
```

For the full example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/zdtHWkxhqhtFPIwWlqWQ?p=preview

Hope this works for you.